# Create Outlook appointment on specific account with command line

Tags: command-line, outlook, appointment, office-2016

I have 2 accounts in my outlook configured, one is for example foo.bar@test.com. When I try to create an appointment via commandline `OUTLOOK.EXE /c ipm.appointment`, the appointment dialog appears, but its not assigend one of my accounts.

I recognize that when I add participant and try to send the appointment. Then the following message appears (translated):

> This appointment is not in the folder "Calendar" for this account. Responses to this appointment will not be recorded. Do you want to contiune?

[image]

**How can I create an appointment which is assigend to the folder "Calendar" to one of the existing accounts?**

Answer (score -1):

You could refer to this code:

```
$fieldservices = "0000000038A1BB1005E5..."
$outlook = new-object -comobject outlook.application
$namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI") 
$calendar = $namespace.GetStoreFromID($fieldservices).GetDefaultFolder(9)
$appt = $Outlook.CreateItem(“olAppointmentItem”)
$root=$store.GetRootFolder()
$cal=$root.Folders.Item(5)
$appt.Move($cal)
#Making the appointment a meeting
$appt.MeetingStatus = 1
#Meeting one hour from current date and time
$appt.Start = $starttime
$appt.End = $appt.Start.AddMinutes($duration)
#Adding required attendees
$appt.RequiredAttendees = $tech
$appt.Subject = "$tech - $company: $summary - $ticket"
$appt.Location = "$address1 $address2 $city $zip"
$appt.Body = $body
$appt.Send()
```

For more information , Please reference this link:

[Powershell Create Outlook Appointment](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/741d7b30-b813-4a4a-b22b-cfcfb739ab26/powershell-create-outlook-appointment?forum=ITCG)